# Exported classes/functions gets wrapped in "default" attribute

Tags: c#, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6

let me preface with saying I am very new to ReactJS and still learning, so I don't have the full grasp of all of its components.

I have tried to setup a simple "hello world" application to understand the flow of information through the code. I am using webpack to wrap all my .js-files into  a main.js file and the exposeloader to access my exposed classes/objects.

My problem is, that when i access the object `Renderings` on the root scope, it should consist of the different exposed classes/functions, and to some extent it does, but they are nested in the `default` attribute, so i have to use `Renderings.default` to access them, why is this? How come it doesn't expose them directly on `Renderings` ?

The application consists of these files:

Hello.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export default class Hello extends React {

  render(){
    return <p>Hello</p>
  }
}
```

World.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export default class World extends React {

  render(){
    return <p>World!</p>
  }
}
```

App.js:

```
import Hello from './hello.js'
import World from './world.js'
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


export default class App extends React {

  render(){    
    return (
      <div><Hello /><World /></div>
    )
  }
}
```

allRenderings.js

```
import App from '../src/app'
import Hello from '../src/hello'
import World from '../src/world'


let renderings = {}

function setupRendering(key, render){
  renderings[key] = render
}

setupRendering('App', App)
setupRendering('Hello', Hello)
setupRendering('World', World)

module.exports = renderings
```

index.js:

```
require('expose-loader?React!react')
require('expose-loader?ReactDOM!react-dom')
require('expose-loader?Renderings!../rendering/allRenderings')
```

webpack.config.js:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

process.noDeprecation = true; 

module.exports = function() {
  var extractCss = new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css')


  var config = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/index.js'),
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/'),
      publicPath: '/',
      filename: '[name].js'
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
      rules: [{
        loader: "babel-loader",
        include: [
          path.resolve("../src"),
          ],
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        options: {
          plugins: ['transform-runtime', 'transform-class-properties'],
          presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-2'],
          },

      }]
    }
  };

  return config
}
```

index.cshtml:

```
<div id="jumbotron" class="jumbotron">
</div>


<script>
    ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Renderings.default.App, { id: 'testApp' }), document.getElementById('jumbotron'))
</script>
```

Comment: Normally you would have a startup script which is part of your source code (and not of index.html) that would setup the initial UI, why do you believe you need to access the built files through the `default` property? It might be even more interesting what would happen if at a later time, you go for a production built and minification as then these will no longer exist

Comment: The `default` property on the object you are `requiring` is based on the module spec for ES6 and is not related directly to `react`.

Comment: As I understand, the exports should be accessed by the `Renderings` keyword. I just don't just understand why the exports are wrapped in the `default` attribute and no directly on the object? I am using an existing project as inspiration to this, which is build in the same fashion, but in that project the exports are accessed directly on the exported object, and contains no `default` properties.

There is a bit more code for the HTML, but it just contains the basic setup for a standard page with head and body tags, which the index.cshtml is then loaded into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I was looking for an answer in the wrong area. The comments helped me realize that this is something related to ES6 and not React.

There seems to be different answers depending on who/where you ask, whether it is related to converting ES6 to ES5, webpack or babel, but more info can be found here:

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/706